# Why is Qt looking for my slot in the base class instead of derived one?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have my class `X` which inherits from Qt's class `Base`. I declared and defined `void mySlot()` slot in my class `X` and I'm connecting some signal to this slot in X's constructor. However, when running my program I get an error message saying there's no such slot as `void mySlot()` in the class `Base`.

Why is the code generated by Meta Object Compiler (moc) looking for my slot in the base class and not in my (derived) class?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Did you add the Q_OBJECT macro on the derived class?

Answer (score 9):

From #qt irc channel

1. Make sure the Q_OBJECT macro is present in the definition of all QObject-derived classes.
2. Make sure you declare your QObject-derived classes in your header files ONLY.
3. Make sure all of your header files are listed in your .pro file in the HEADERS= list.
4. Run qmake every time you add Q_OBJECT to one of your classes or modify your .pro file.